# Who is Tessa, and why do they have a profile in my Chromium?

Tags: chromium

When I browse to `chrome://signin-dice-web-intercept/?debug` it says,

> **Continue in a new Chromium profile?** Tessa is already signed in to this Chromium profile. To keep your browsing separate, Chromium can create your own profile for you.

Who is Tessa?

Comment: @John it's chromium-specific.

Comment: I get the same thing, actually.  `Tessa is already signed in to this Chrome profile.  This will create a new Chrome profile for sam.sample@intercepted.com`

Comment: @John Definitely not the case here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is just the default name of the profile when you you don't log in on Chromium, you can see it in the code in [`dice_web_signin_interception_bubble_view_browsertest.cc`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/views/profiles/dice_web_signin_interception_bubble_view_browsertest.cc;drc=101f4cc62642c7fbf80e20e10fc3bd3811a555e9;l=216),

```
    primary_account.account_id = CoreAccountId::FromGaiaId("primary_ID");
    primary_account.given_name = "Tessa";
    primary_account.full_name = "Tessa Tester";
    primary_account.email = "tessa.tester@primary.com";
    primary_account.hosted_domain =
        is_primary_account_managed ? "primary.com" : kNoHostedDomainFound;
```

However it seems like a poor idea to tell you that you're "already signed in" to an account that you never signed in to, and don't recognize.

Comment: Wondered if this was the case, but was too lazy to go find the code

Comment: @squillman they don't call me "The Most Useful Member of SuperUser" for nothing! ;)

Comment: @EvanCarroll Who are these "they"? :)

Comment: @EvanCarroll - no, they're saying you're the most useful for nothing :D

Comment: @JaromandaX Of course they would say I'm the most useful, for nothing. Wtf would I have to give them something to say the truth?